# mvpa2.suite: Runtime warning and erro in Python 2.7.6

Tags: python-2.7

I just installed mvpa2 module on my ubuntu 14.04, Python 2.7.6. following the instruction at http://www.pymvpa.org/installation.html using `sudo aptitude install python-mvpa2`

Command `import mvpa2` works well, but when I run `from mvpa2.suite import *` , I get the followin warning in my terminal:

**/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/pls.py:7: DeprecationWarning: This module has been moved to cross_decomposition and will be removed in 0.16
  "removed in 0.16", DeprecationWarning)**

And also fallowing error:

**TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'rho'**

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually this warning comes from the import done by mdp, which PyMVPA optionally uses... you can safely ignore it (no upgrade of PyMVPA would help anyhow), because even if it gets completely removed, then mdp would simply skip that import and you would remain 'golden'.

Answer (score 0):

That problem is due to an incompatibility of the python-mvpa2 and scikit-learn versions. You can check more details on that in this [page](https://github.com/PyMVPA/PyMVPA/blob/master/mvpa2/clfs/warehouse.py), because depends on which scikit-learn version you have what will be the parameters to call a given function.

A short solution is to uninstall your python-mvpa2 and scikit-learn, and install them directly from their github repos:

- [python-mvpa2] `https://github.com/PyMVPA`
- [scikit-learn] `https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn`

I just did it and now the example `doc/examples/som.py` (for my case) is working perfectly.